# Getting the id of the dynamic element clicked

Tags: javascript, php, addeventlistener

I have a for loop that creates several dynamic elements:

```
// unknown length of $data['x']
<?php foreach($data['x'] as $x): ?>
    <button id="button_id<?php echo $x['id'] ?>" type="button" name="button">button</button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

which results in:

```
<button type="button" id="button_id2" name="button">button</button>
<button type="button" id="button_id4" name="button">button</button>
<button type="button" id="button_id9" name="button">button</button>
```

I want to get the id by clicking the element button. I managed to do it with adding onclick to html but since it's a bad practice how to i catch the element via eventlistener ?

Comment: use class to achieve this

Comment: use class instead of id, so no need to assign unique id to each button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var allButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

var clickFunction = function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
};

for (var i = 0; i < allButton.length; i++) {
    allButton[i].addEventListener('click', clickFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button_id2" name="button">button</button>
<button type="button" id="button_id4" name="button">button</button>
<button type="button" id="button_id9" name="button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `ID` attribute altogether if the task is really to identify which button was clicked as there are better ways than relying upon the ID. The following uses `querySelectorAll` to identify all the relevant nodes to which it is easy to assign an event listener

```
<?php

    for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ )echo "<button data-id='$i' name='bttn$i'>Button $i</button>";

?>
<script>
    let col=document.querySelectorAll('button');
        col.forEach( bttn=>{
            bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                alert( this.dataset.id )
            })
        })
</script>
```